# Make column buttons of same size in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want all buttons take full space as the max length column space. I have tried using Intrinsicheight, Table, Row-column but still not able to solve this.

I can solve this problem in HTML/CSS using flex but not in flutter.

Here is the what I can achieve till now,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: IntrinsicHeight(
                child: Table(
//           defaultColumnWidth:
//               FixedColumnWidth(150.0), // Adjust this value as needed
          border: TableBorder.all(color: Colors.yellow),
          children: [
            TableRow(
              children: [
                TableCell(
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text(
                        'Button with Long Text 1 text text text text text text text text text text text text text'),
                  ),
                ),
                TableCell(
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text('Button 2'),
                  ),
                ),
                TableCell(
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text('Button 3'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ))),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      'Hello, World!',
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it mandatory to have Table for your use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,` with Row widget.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: IntrinsicHeight(
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text('Button with Long Text 1 text text text text text text text text text text text text text'),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text('Button 2'),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text('Button 3'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How can we do this without IntrinsicHeight??

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal of making all buttons take up the full space of the maximum length column, you can use the `Expanded` widget within a `Row` for each button. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this: dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text(
                  'Button with Long Text 1 text text text text text text text text text text text text text',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text('Button 2'),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text('Button 3'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Check the script and let me know.

Comment: Your code is not giving script error, I have already tried chatGpt extensively.